# What is the difference between continue, break, fall-through, throw and return in SWIFT?

Tags: swift

Could someone help explain to me the differences between these keywords in Swift?

- `continue`
- `break`
- `fallthrough`
- `throw`
- `return`

Comment: Those commands are borrowed from other languages and work as expected; no surprises. However to know exactly how they should be used you need to read the language description from Apple; "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)". This is available for free. I got mine through iBooks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Continue:**

> A continue statement ends program execution of the current iteration of a loop statement but does not stop execution of the loop statement. ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html))

```
var sum = 0;
for var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ {
    if i == 4 {
        continue //this ends this iteration of the loop
    }
    sum += i //thus, 0, 1, 2, and 3 will be added to this, but not 4
}
```

**Break:**

> A break statement ends program execution of a loop, an if statement, or a switch statement. ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html))

```
var sum = 0;
for var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ {
    if i == 2 {
        break //this ends the entire loop
    }
    sum += i //thus only 0 and 1 will be added
}
```

**Fallthrough:**

> A fallthrough statement causes program execution to continue from one case in a switch statement to the next case. ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html))

```
var sum = 0
var i = 3
switch i {
case 1:
    sum += i
case 2:
    sum += i
case 3:
    sum += i
    fallthrough //allows for the next case to be evaluated
case i % 3:
    sum += i
}
```

**Throw:**

> You use a throw statement to throw an error. ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html))

You could throw an error like the one below that says that five more coins are needed due to insufficient funds.

```
throw VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: 5)
```

**Return:**

> A return statement occurs in the body of a function or method definition and causes program execution to return to the calling function or method. ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html))

```
func myMethod(){
    newMethod()
}

func newMethod(){
    var sum = 0;
    sum += 2;
    if sum > 1 {
        return //jumps back to myMethod()
    }
    sum += 3; //this statement will never be executed
}
```

Returns can also be used to return a value from the function.

```
func myFunc() {
    let value = newFunc() //assigns 5 to "value"
}

func newFunc() -> Int {
    return 5 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminLowry .It is very useful for me

Comment: @Honestraj19 if my post answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer as so other users looking at this post can be helped in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the concepts of Viewdidload,Viewwillappear and Viewdisappear?

Comment: @Honestraj19 You should post a new question for this. Also, because this question was put on hold for being "too broad", I would consider making your question about those three methods a little more specific.